# How to read last line with Scanner.nextLine()?

Tags: java

I'm working on homework and i have to read input with nextLine() method. When i copied all input lines and pasted on console, the program don't read final line. How can i solve this problem.

What i need :

```
line1
line2
line3
```

What i get:

```
line1
line2
```

Here is my code

```
public class Name{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = scn.nextLine();

        while(scn.hasNextLine()){
        .
        .
        .
        str = scn.nextLine();
        }
        scn.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason to check for `null` - you should be using `scn.hasNextLine()` instead, which will stop iteration when there are no more lines in the file for the `Scanner` to read.

Here's a code sample - we move the reading of `System.in` into the loop, and add a stopping condition so you don't get an infinite loop.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String str;

while(scn.hasNextLine()){
    str = scn.nextLine();
    System.out.println(str);
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
public void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scn.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = scn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    // don't close System.in as we didn't create it.
}
```

When I run

```
$ cat > text
line1
line2
line3
^D
$ java -cp . Example < text
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: The output is the same :(

Comment: @user3460845 in that case you are doing something else wrong. See my example which shows the code works.